# moment value can not init data-picker module

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, angular-bootstrap

I use **$scope.dt= moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")** to init datapicker module.
`<p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
      </p>`

this is plnkr [test code.](http://embed.plnkr.co/fcXYx6/).
why this can not show value on input?

Answer (score 1):

Moment returns the date as a string, rather than a date object, which is what the datepicker requires, so you need to convert it to a date.

Ex:

```
$scope.today = function() {
  $scope.dt = moment().toDate();

};
$scope.today();
```

You'll then need to format that if you want it to display properly outside of the datepicker, which you can do when you call it in your view:

```
{{dt | date: "yyyy-MM-dd" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why moment format value can not init module?
the old version support this.